# Intersection of two lists

Tags: haskell

I have two lists of integers. I need to get common elements of two lists using recursion.
For example:

```
intersect [1, 2, 4, 6] [5, 4, 2, 5, 7] == [2, 4] (or [4, 2]!)
intersect [1, 2, 4, 6] [3, 5, 7] == []
```

I did it with two functions.

```
inlist :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool 
inlist _ [] = False 
inlist x (y:ys) | x==y = True 
                | otherwise = inlist x ys

intersect :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
intersect _ [] = []
intersect [] _ = []
intersect (x:xs) (y:ys) 
  | inlist x (y:ys) && not (null xs) = x : intersect xs (y:ys)
  | not (null xs) = intersect xs (y:ys)
  | inlist x (y:ys) = [x]
  | otherwise = []
```

How to make it easier?

Comment: The `intersect` function you wrote does not work with *empty* lists: you do the `null` check on `xs`, so the *tail* of the list.

Comment: Thank you @willem-van-onsem. Fixed this.

Comment: not sure if StackOverflow is the right place for a question like this - seems you are asking for a code review right?

Comment: What's supposed to happen with repetitions? What should `intersect [5] [5,5]` and `intersect [5,5] [5,5]` be? Do you care about the order of the elements in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can rewrite

```hs
inlist :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool 
inlist _ [] = False 
inlist x (y:ys) | x==y = True 
                | otherwise = inlist x ys
```

As

```hs
inlist _ [] = False
inlist x (y:ys) = x == y || inlist x ys
```

Also, the function `inlist` is actually part of the Prelude - it's known as `elem` (`elem :: forall a . Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`). So we should use the library function `elem` instead.

Your intersection code needlessly considers more cases than necessary. We can rewrite it as follows:

```hs
intersect [] _ = []
intersect (x:xs) ys = if elem x ys
                      then x : intersect xs ys
                      else intersect xs ys
```

Note that there are only 3 cases that we need to consider here instead of 6. Most of your cases are redundant.

In fact, we can further simplify this to

```hs
intersect xs ys = filter (\x -> elem x ys) xs
```

Using the library function `filter`. If we switch the arguments, we get

```hs
intersect ys xs = filter (\x -> elem x ys) xs
```

That is,

```hs
intersect ys = filter $ \x -> elem x ys
```

Finally, we can rewrite `\x -> elem x ys` as `\x -> flip elem ys x`, which is in turn equal to `flip elem ys`. So we have

```hs
intersect ys = filter $ flip elem ys
```

That is,

```hs
intersect ys = filter . flip elem $ ys
```

```hs
intersect = filter . flip elem
```

This is the most compact way to write `intersect`.

Advanced note: that this is not the asymptotically optimal way to take the intersection, as the runtime complexity will be `O(length xs * length ys)`. To improve the time complexity, we can sort both lists ahead of time and then merge the sorted lists (it's possible to take the intersection of sorted lists in linear time). To achieve optimal complexity, we can use radix sort as our sorting algorithm (implementing array-based radix sort in Haskell is possible but requires either linear types or the `ST` monad, but it's actually possible to implement radix sort without arrays using Tries). The optimal implementation will thus be a linear-time implementation.

Comment: `Integer` isn't a fixed-width type, so radix sort will not be linear time.

Comment: @dfeuer You are correct that it is not linear in the length of the lists if we use `Integer`. However, it is linear in the total amount of memory (ie the sum of the number of digits of all elements of the lists), which is asymptotically optimal. Note that technically, the `(==)` and `(<)` functions are not constant time when dealing with `Integer`s, so the runtime of the original implementation of `intersect` is actually worse than indicated since it depends on the size of the elements of `xs` and `ys` (ie it would be `O(sum [log (2 + min (abs x) (abs y)) | x <- xs, y <- ys])`).

Answer (score 0):

A Hoogle search for [`Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Eq%20a%20%3D%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D) yields [`intersect`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersect). To make it simpler, just use that.